# How use media-quires in CSS?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm making web-site , and i need make adaptive site. So i began use media-quires and got a trouble. When screen resolution has been changing  in example since 2560px to 1920px , some styles remain in site, however they hasn't written in code CSS, why ?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 2560px ) {
    body {
        background-color: #344B56;
        color: white;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        margin: 0px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .info {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: flex-start;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .company {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        .company p {
            margin: 0px;
        }

    .hours, .adress, .callback {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }


    .logo {
        width: 50px;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        padding: 20px;
        border-top: 1px white solid;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

    .completed {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        border-bottom: 2px skyblue solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .navbar a {
        letter-spacing: -2px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .navbar a:hover {
            color: skyblue;
        }

    .company_info {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #323a42;
    }

    .company_text {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 500px;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .infoCompany {
        background-image: url("./images/companyBack.jpeg");
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
    }

    .infoCompany__Text {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 26px;
    }

    .infoCompany__Text_Company {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

    .Service {
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-right: 200px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .Service__Products {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .Service__Products_Product {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

        .Service__Products_Product:not(first-child) {
            margin-left: 150px;
        }

    .Product__img {
        width: 500px;
        height: 402px;
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    }

    .Product__DownPartCard {
        display: flex;
    }

    .Product__LeftDivCard {
        width: 24px;
        height: 98px;
        background-color: #1A81AD;
    }

    .Product__NameCardDiv {
        width: 476px;
        height: 98px;
        background: white;
    }

    .Product__DownPartCard_Text {
        font-size: 18px;
        display: flex;
        color: black;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .Garant {
        color: white;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-right: 200px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .Garant__Garants {
        margin-top: 70px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .Garant__Card {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .Gatant__Card_Img {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    .Gatant__Card_Text {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    footer {
        margin-top: 70px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px white solid;
    }

    .invisible {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px ) {
    body {
        background-color: #344B56;
        color: white;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        margin: 0px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .info {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: flex-start;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .company {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        .company p {
            margin: 0px;
        }

    .hours, .adress, .callback {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }


    .logo {
        width: 50px;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        padding: 20px;
        border-top: 1px white solid;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

    .completed {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        border-bottom: 2px skyblue solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .navbar a {
        letter-spacing: -2px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .navbar a:hover {
            color: skyblue;
        }

    .company_info {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #323a42;
    }

    .company_text {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 500px;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .infoCompany {
        background-image: url("./images/companyBack.jpeg");
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
    }

    .infoCompany__Text {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 26px;
    }

    .infoCompany__Text_Company {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

    .Service {
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-right: 200px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .Service__Products {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .Service__Products_Product {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .Product__img {
        width: 400px;
        height: 302px;
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    }

    .Product__DownPartCard {
        display: flex;
    }

    .Product__LeftDivCard {
        width: 12px;
        height: 98px;
        background-color: #1A81AD;
    }

    .Product__NameCardDiv {
        width: 388px;
        height: 98px;
        background: white;
    }

    .Product__DownPartCard_Text {
        font-size: 15px;
        display: flex;
        color: black;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .Garant {
        color: white;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-right: 200px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .Garant__Garants {
        margin-top: 70px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .Garant__Card {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .Gatant__Card_Img {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    .Gatant__Card_Text {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    footer {
        margin-top: 70px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px white solid;
    }

    .invisible {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
    body {
        background-color: #344B56;
        color: white;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        margin: 0px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .info {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: flex-start;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .company {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        .company p {
            margin: 0px;
        }

    .hours, .adress, .callback {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }


    .logo {
        width: 50px;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        padding: 20px;
        border-top: 1px white solid;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

    .completed {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        border-bottom: 2px skyblue solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .navbar a {
        letter-spacing: -2px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .navbar a:hover {
            color: skyblue;
        }

    .company_info {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #323a42;
    }

    .company_text {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 500px;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .infoCompany {
        background-image: url("./images/companyBack.jpeg");
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
    }

    .infoCompany__Text {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 26px;
    }

    .infoCompany__Text_Company {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

    .Service {
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .Service__Products {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .Service__Products_Product {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    }

    .Product__img {
        width: 400px;
        height: 302px;
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    }

    .Product__downPartCard {
        display: flex;
    }

    .Product__leftDivCard {
        width: 12px;
        height: 98px;
        background-color: #1A81AD;
    }

    .Product__NameCardDiv {
        width: 388px;
        height: 98px;
        background: white;
    }

    .Product__DownPartCard_Text {
        font-size: 15px;
        display: flex;
        color: black;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .Garant {
        color: white;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-right: 200px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .Garant__Garants {
        margin-top: 70px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .Garant__Card {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .Gatant__Card_Img {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    .Gatant__Card_Text {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    footer {
        margin-top: 70px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px white solid;
    }

    .invisible {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

So "margin-left: 150px ;" from media 2560px  somehow using in 1920px, why ?

```
.Service__products_Product:not(first-child) {
    margin-left: 150px ;
}
```

Comment: You specified `max-width`, so for any with *below* `2560px`, the styles will apply. You might want `min-width`...

Comment: `.Service__Products_Product:not(first-child)` is not a valid selector: all pseudoclasses have a `:` prefix, so use `.Service__Products_Product:not(:first-child)`.